# Select all child elements of body with 6 degrees of separation

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, less

Is there a LESS, CSS or JQuery selector for 'All child elements N degrees away'? For example for the `body` I want to select all its child elements with 2 degrees of separation. So I want all the first child elements and their first child elements.

To make it harder I wont know what elements the body contains as the code could be used on any website AND I will most likely be using 6 degrees of separation not 2.

Is this correct and is it very inefficient? `body > *, body > * > *, body > * > * > *, body > * > * > * > *, body > * > * > * > * > *, body > * > * > * > * > *`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you're writing css selectors for html you don't control?

Comment: Its a jquery library other users will use on their website.